# Get some error when splitting file in nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

The error is:

> throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but
>   got a ' + gettype(fn))

The file (app.js) looks like this:

```
const express = require( 'express' )
const app = express()
const product = require( './api/routes/products')


app.use('/products', product )


module.exports = app;
```

And then it said in nodemon:

> throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but
>   got a ' + gettype(fn))

This is my file products.js:

```
const express = require( 'express' )
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', ( req, res, next ) => {
  res.status( 200 ).json( {
    test: 'got it'
  } )
})
```

Is there something missing? I use express 4.0.16.

Answer (score 0):

app.use accepts a function to apply to requests. Your products.js doesn't export anything, so when you require it the variable product is not a function. Try setting module.exports to the handler function instead of passing it to the router.